# Manage multiple Machine Signing Identity For One Individual developer profile

Tags: ios, certificate, code-signing, iphone-developer-program, code-signing-certificate

How we can set multiple machine signing identity for one developer account.Currently i can able to use only one signing identity if i add another machine certificate it replace the previous machine signing identity.So How multiple machine can used to development for one individual developer account
Any help should be appropriate.

Comment: You need to sign it with one machine and export the profile to the other machines.

Comment: Export the p.12 file and from other machine double click that p.12 file.
You will see the certificate is added in your keychain

Answer (score 0):

Go to keychain access check the left column select login from top (Keychains) and My Certificates from category column , you will see the iPhone Developer Certificate you will get the arrow just beside that dropdown it you will get a key sign just right click on that and check the screenshot now click on export you will get the p12 file , you can send that file anywhere you want .[image]

In other mac just double click the p12 file inorder to install